# How to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default value in Magento DDL

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ddl

I am updating my table structure and everything work good, but default value for column `created_at` is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` again and again.

I want it to be equal to current time (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Here is my current code:

```
$table->addColumn($tableBanners, 'created_at', [
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    'nullable' => false,
    'comment'  => 'created_at',
    'default'  => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `'default'` section, change to `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT`. So that:

```
'default'  => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT
```

Ref: https://code007.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/magento-how-to-create-a-timestamp-table-column-with-current_timestamp-as-default-value/

Comment: Yes, I've just found this solution :)

Comment: Please accept my answer then :)

Comment: And for `updated_at` columns use `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE` as default.

Comment: @clockworkgeek : Actually now it seems to be `Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE`, thanks for the hint !

Comment: @AdrienFERREIRAAlioze - Yes it's all different now with Magento 2.

Comment: For anyone who finds themself here and confused why this isn't working on your DATETIME column, this ONLY works for TIMESTAMP columns.  I don't know why Magento never bothered to include support for a default value on a DATETIME column, maybe that's not standard practice (it *is* supported by MySQL).  If you need to add a DATETIME column with a default, run a raw query directly using `$installer->run('...')`

Answer (score -2):

You can use these for equal value for current timestamp

```
date('Y-m-d G:i:s')
```